# Are flights to Jodhpur safe?

Tags: air-travel, india, safety, pakistan

I'm planning to travel to the region of Rajasthan in India next october, and I've read that some airports (like Jaisalmer) are closed due to the conflict with Pakistan.

So I thought of flying to Jodhpur, so that I can reach Jaisalmer by bus or train and then bus all the way back with all the cities to visit.

But: are flights to Jodhpur safe or is there some concern due to the conflict?

Comment: If Jaisalmer airport itself is closed, isn’t there a broader question about the safety of your proposed itinerary than just ‘which airport’?

Comment: @Traveller I think Jaisalmer airport is closed due to a lack of traffic from Jaisalmer, than safety.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment, relations between India and Pakistan while still fraught with tension, are not so tense as to not travel to Jodhpur by flight. Of course, these things are not static, and might change at any time.

Looking at the Airports Authority of India's [website](https://www.aai.aero/en/airports/security-info/jodhpur) for Jodhpur airport, I don't see any information of a travel advisory indicating that it is not safe to do so.

Additionally, you could also rely on your country's travel advisory, which is often very specific to certain parts of India.

Answer (score 1):

'Safe' is of course subjective, but [looking at a list of recent arrivals at JDH](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/jdh/arrivals) suggests the airport is operating just fine.